# Improving type-check for different types of Iterable<T>

Tags: java, generics

Looks like List, Set, Queue all implement Iterable in Java. I have this annoying bit of logic that handles each type. One of the special cases is a Set where I pass the key/value of each entry as separate args.

```
    if (i instanceof Set) {
      if (v instanceof Map.Entry) {
        ((IEacherWithTypedIndex) m).each(((Map.Entry) v).getValue(), ((Map.Entry) v).getKey(), taskRunner);
      } else {
        ((IEacherWithTypedIndex) m).each(v, v, taskRunner);
      }
    } else if (i instanceof List) {
      ((IEacherWithTypedIndex) m).each(v, val, taskRunner);
    } else if (i instanceof Queue) {
      ((IEacherWithTypedIndex) m).each(v, v, taskRunner);
    } else {
      ((IEacherWithTypedIndex) m).each(v, val, taskRunner);
    }
```

is there any way to reduce this logic down? Besides List, Set, Queue, is there anything else I should handle?

The related interfaces are:

```
  public interface IEacherWithTypedIndex<T, V, E> extends IEach {
    void each(T v, V i, IEachCallback<E> cb);
  }

  public interface IEachCallback<E> {
    void done(E e);
  }
```

Comment: It would really help if 1) we could see types of all variables; 2) we could understand meaning of all variables (e.g. what is `v` and what is `val`); 3) you could describe a use case. So far it feels like you are doing something really weird, especially since you don't use `i` itself.

Comment: @ReputationFarmer np, i is the `Iterable`, and v is the value of the iterable as in `Iterable<V>` or `var v  = iterable.iterator.next()`. val is an integer index.